# SMLcircularity Error of operand and operator don't agree

Tags: error-handling, compiler-errors, smlnj

```
    fun insert R x [] acc = [x]
  | insert R x (h::t) acc =
    if R (x,h) then acc::(x::(h::t))
    else(
        acc=acc::h;
        insert R x t acc
        );
fun isort_aux R [] acc = acc
  | isort_aux R (x::xs) acc =
    isort_aux xs (insert R x acc [])
fun isort_2 R xs = isort_aux R xs []
```

I am trying to write a tail recursive code for insertion sort in sml for which i made a accumulator 'acc' but in line 5 acc=acc::h is giving the following error

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.78 [built: Thu Aug 31 03:45:42 2017]
- stdIn:5.3-5.13 Error: operator and operand don't agree [circularity]
  operator domain: 'Z * 'Z list
  operand:         'Z * 'Z
  in expression:
    acc :: h
-
```

Comment: `acc = acc::h` is a comparison, and you can't cons `h` and `acc` together. You should probably review the basics of SML, and start with writing down the types explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

> acc=acc::h;
>   insert R x t acc

Having two calls here doesn't work in SML. You can only do one thing in SML because of the way the language is structured. I did this when starting out on SML a few weeks ago and it didn't work for me.

As the comment by @moldbnilo said your code is trying to compare acc to acc::h and not setting it equal to acc.

I am very new to SML so take this with a grain of salt as it may not be right.